# How to check if a string has numbers and letters of alphabet

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, filter

I am wondering if strings have functionality that can see if a string contains words or words and other types of characters in general. (ideally I want to only consider strings that have readable sentences but that may too advanced) I am trying to count strings in a list that have that kind of text. I do not want to add to the count any strings that are *only* numbers, blank spaces, tabs or symbols (like ?, @, #) or even random letters unless there is at least some words contained in the string.

The strings will be initialised with "" so the code in the if statement - **(this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().ElementAt(j).getError() != "")** - would be fine if there was no input at all. Unfortunately I am expecting some input in some case so this case also counts scenarios where there are only spaces, number, symbols or all of the 3 - which I do not want.

this is referring to a class inheriting from List
.getNotarised() returns a List

```
/** Find the highest/lowest amount of errors/solutions/suggestions/comments.
         *  If it's ASC then return the lowest to highest.
         *  If it's DESC then return the highest to lowest.
         *  Return a list with LOGS in the correct order.
         *  */
        public List<LOG> highORlow(string asc_desc, string category)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int[] array = new int[this.Count()];

            for(int i = 0; i <= this.Count()-1; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j <= this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().Count()-1; j++)
                {
                    if(this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().ElementAt(j).getError() != "")
                    {
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
                array[i] = count;

            }



            return new List<LOG>();
        }
```

Comment: Looks like a job for Regex. Did you already consider this?

Comment: Oh thank-you @KlausGütter. I come from coding in C++ so I'm still learning the different features available. I will give it a go

Comment: I tried using the pattern "[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{0}" and it works well. Thanks for the help! I'm not sure if there is incorrect input that will go through because I don't fully understand RegExp yet so I'm hoping this will be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point of interest:
**string pattern = "[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{0}";
Regex xp = new Regex(pattern);**

Use **xp.IsMatch()** to check if the pattern is matched.

````
/** Find the highest/lowest amount of errors/solutions/suggestions/comments.
         *  If it's true (ASC) then return the lowest to highest.
         *  If it's false (DESC) then return the highest to lowest.
         *  Return a list with LOGS in the correct order.
         *  */
        public List<LOG> highORlow(bool asc_desc, string category)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string pattern = "[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{0}";
            Regex xp = new Regex(pattern);
            Dictionary<LOG, int> array = new Dictionary<LOG, int>();


            for (int i = 0; i <= this.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().Count() - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (category == "ERROR")
                    {
                        if (xp.IsMatch(this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().ElementAt(j).getError()))
                        {
                            ++count;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if (category == "SOLUTION")
                    {
                        if (xp.IsMatch(this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().ElementAt(j).getSolution()))
                        {
                            ++count;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if (category == "SUGGESTION")
                    {
                        if (xp.IsMatch(this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().ElementAt(j).getSuggestion()))
                        {
                            ++count;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if (category == "COMMENT")
                    {
                        if (xp.IsMatch(this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised().ElementAt(j).getComment()))
                        {
                            ++count;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                array.Add(this.ElementAt(i), count);
                count = 0;
            }

            List<LOG> list = new List<LOG>();
            
            if(asc_desc)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<LOG, int> v in array.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
                {
                    list.Add(v.Key);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<LOG, int> v in array.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value))
                {
                    list.Add(v.Key);
                }
            }



            return list;
        }```
````

Comment: Minor tip: instead of `i <= this.Count() - 1` in the `for`, just use `i < this.Count()`

Comment: How much work is it to calculate `this.ElementAt(i).getNotarised()`? Fill a variable with that result just before the "j" loop - that saves duplicate work

Comment: Thanks @HansKeﬆing. I come from C++ so I didn't want to take shortcuts until I was comfortable with C#. I understand what you're saying.